# meteor export mongo URL issue in my local

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have my own system mongodb in my local machine(port : 27017)

And my meteor application is running same mahine fine when i am using the meteor mongo(port : 28017)

I have tried use the my system mongo using the floowing command

export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/ibm_project

Meteor Server started properly.

when i tried to access the URL, after couple of minutes, my system/PC is  shuting down.

I am not sure what's wrong I am doing and can you please help me

Comment: BTW. When Saw the system process in linux
Firefox is taking 113% CPU Usage and Node and Mongo is taking more and more

Comment: Please help me to understand

Comment: Please see when i see the mongo output
<br />

Sun Feb  1 22:43:35.728 [conn4] getmore flipproject.member cursorid:721251542510140 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 4 locks(micros) r:85254 nreturned:27612 reslen:4194544 11

Answer (score 1):

Are you using windows command prompt? first check by typing below command

**meteor mongo --url**

above command will display your mongo url.If you want to run any other database in your local app, go to root folder and type below command

**set MONGO_URL=mongodb://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[databasename]**

eg-set MONGO_URL=mongodb://root:abcde@ds049476.mlab.com:48474/mydb

above command is working on windows